# IF COL_LENGTH('EMP_NUM','EMPLOYEE') IS NOT NULL - EQUIVALENT IN ORACLE

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, oracle11g

I am having the below script in SQL server to alter the column to allow **null** to **not null**.

What will be the equivalent syntax in Oracle 11g or above for the same?

```
IF COL_LENGTH('EMP_NUM','EMPLOYEE') IS NOT NULL
   ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEEALTER COLUMN EMP_NUMnumeric(10,0) NOT NULL;
```

Comment: *"i have researched and don't find anything"* The [first result](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-not-null/) in my search looked very promising. What about that article didn't you understand? (Note, I have never used Oracle, and have no idea of the differences in syntaxes between T-SQL and PL/SQL).

Comment: @Larnu If i run the alter command without checking the existing column. I am getting the error like below Error report -
ORA-01442: column to be modified to NOT NULL is already NOT NULL

Comment: *"column to be modified to NOT NULL is already NOT NULL"*... And what about that don't you understand; looks pretty clear to me.

Comment: @Larnu How do you check and skip in the script? That's my question. I don't want to alter the column which is already not nul and i want to alter the column which allows null. How do you write the oracle statement for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle, you have to use dynamic SQL as you can't execute DDL in PL/SQL *as is*. Why PL/SQL? Because `IF-THEN-ELSE` *is* PL/SQL, not SQL.

Presuming this is part of your PL/SQL procedure, you'd then

```
if col_length('EMP_NUM', 'EMPLOYEE') is not null then
  execute immediate 'alter table employee modify emp_num not null';
end if;
```

---

That's for the `ALTER` part. However, as Oracle doesn't have COL_LENGTH function (nor anything like that, as far as I can tell), you have to do it yourself. Here's  an example:

A table whose column allows nulls:

```
SQL> create table employee (emp_num number);

Table created.
```

Check the `Null?` column - empty, so yes - it allows nulls.

```
SQL> desc employee;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 EMP_NUM                                            NUMBER
```

Query data dictionary to find column's length:

```
SQL> select data_length from user_tab_columns
  2  where table_name = 'EMPLOYEE'
  3    and column_name = 'EMP_NUM';

DATA_LENGTH
-----------
         22
```

Finally, your future PL/SQL procedure:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_len number;
  3  begin
  4    select data_length
  5      into l_len
  6      from user_tab_columns
  7      where table_name = 'EMPLOYEE'
  8        and column_name = 'EMP_NUM';
  9
 10    if l_len is not null then
 11       execute immediate 'alter table employee modify emp_num not null';
 12    end if;
 13  end;
 14  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> desc employee;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 EMP_NUM                                   NOT NULL NUMBER

SQL>
```

As you can see, the `Null?` column now contains `NOT NULL` which means that `ALTER TABLE` was successfully executed.

---

Additionally, you can even create your own function to query column's data length and then use it in your procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace function col_length(par_table in varchar2, par_column in varchar2)
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    retval user_tab_columns.data_length%type;
  5  begin
  6    select data_length
  7      into retval
  8      from user_tab_columns
  9      where table_name = par_table
 10        and column_name = par_column;
 11    return retval;
 12  end;
 13  /

Function created.

SQL> select col_length('EMPLOYEE', 'EMP_NUM') from dual;

COL_LENGTH('EMPLOYEE','EMP_NUM')
--------------------------------
                              22

SQL>
```

Finally:

```
SQL> drop table employee;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table employee (emp_num number);

Table created.

SQL> begin
  2    if col_length('EMPLOYEE', 'EMP_NUM') is not null then
  3       execute immediate 'alter table employee modify emp_num not null';
  4    end if;
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> desc employee;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 EMP_NUM                                   NOT NULL NUMBER

SQL>
```